# Issue with Form Submission and Middleware in Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a problem with form submission in Laravel, where the data is not being posted to the server. The goal is to create an admin account through the registration form. To prevent multiple admin account creation, I have created a custom middleware called CheckSetup that checks if there is an existing user with the "admin" role in the database. If not, the user should be redirected to the setup page to create an admin account.

However, I am encountering an issue with the form submission. When I fill in the registration form and click the "Register" button, the form does not submit, and the page simply reloads. I have verified that the form includes the CSRF token, the form's action attribute points to the correct route, and the route is defined as a POST route in my web.php routes file.

I have also added logging statements in the createAdmin method of the SetupController to check if the form data is being received, and the data is logged correctly.

Middleware (CheckSetup): The CheckSetup middleware is added to the web middleware group. It checks if there are any users with the "admin" role in the database. If no admin user exists and the current route is not the setup route, the user is redirected to the setup page to create an admin account.

User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_type', // Add 'user_type' to the $fillable array

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

web route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'setup.check'], function () {
    // All your existing routes go here

    Route::get('/', Index::class);
    Route::get('setup', [SetupController::class, 'showAdminSetup'])->name('livewire.register');
    Route::post('setup', [SetupController::class, 'createAdmin'])->name('livewire.register');

})
Route::get('login', Login::class);
    Route::get('register', Register::class);
```

setupController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; // Add this line to import the Log class

class SetupController extends Controller
{
    // Existing code...

    public function showAdminSetup()
    {
        // Check if there are any users with the "admin" role in the database
        $adminExists = User::where('user_type', 'admin')->exists();

        // If an admin user exists, redirect to the login page
        if ($adminExists) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        // If no admin user exists, show the setup page to create an admin account
        return view('livewire.register');
    }

    public function createAdmin(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('Request method: ' . $request->input('name'));
        Log::info('Request method: ' . $request->input('email'));
        Log::info('Request method: ' . $request->input('password'));

           // Validate the request data
           $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        // Create the admin user in the database
        User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
            'user_type' => 'admin',
        ]);

        // Redirect to the login page
        return redirect('/login')->with('success', 'Admin account created successfully. You can now log in as an admin.');

        // Check if there are any users with the "admin" role in the database
        $adminExists = User::where('user_type', 'admin')->exists();

        // If an admin user exists, redirect to the login page
        if ($adminExists) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        // If no admin user exists and the request method is GET, show the setup page to create an admin account
        return view('livewire.register');
    }

    // Rest of the code...
}
```

Middleware CheckStup

```
<?php
// app/Http/Middleware/CheckSetup.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\User;

class CheckSetup
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if there are any users with the "admin" role in the database
        $adminExists = User::where('user_type', 'admin')->exists();

        // If no admin user exists, redirect to the setup page to create an admin account
        if (!$adminExists && $request->route()->getName() !== 'livewire.register') {
            return redirect()->route('livewire.register');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // Add the StartSession middleware here

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
            \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // Move StartSession here
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSetup::class, // Add the setup check middleware here
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class, // Add the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware here
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];


    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'setup.check' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSetup::class,
        'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAuthenticated::class,
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

register blade

```html
@extends('layouts.custom-app1')

@section('styles')
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container text-center text-dark">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 d-block mx-auto">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-6">
                                       
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Register</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Create New Account</p>
                                    <form action="{{ route('livewire.register') }}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-white"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-user w-4 text-muted-dark"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Enter name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-white"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-envelope text-muted-dark w-4"></i></span>
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Enter Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-white"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-unlock-alt text-muted-dark w-4"></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                               
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
@endsection
```

Despite these efforts, the form data is not being posted to the server, and the admin account is not being created. I suspect there might be an issue with the form submission or the use of Laravel's form validation.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am confused, you are checking if an admin account exists, but once you have 1 admin user, the middleware will ALWAYS redirect to the other part, do you want to only have 1 admin in your system? And when you have a middleware that should or will only act on 1 route, do not make it global and add a check for a route, add the middleware to that specific route on the route definition and remove the route check on the middleware...

Comment: Yes . need checking if an admin account exists .  once you have 1 admin user, the middleware will ALWAYS redirect to the other part.

Comment: Okay, so you have 1 admin, there is no possibility for 2 or more admins. In that case, I would still not make it global, and just use `->middleware(....)` in the route and add it to it. So, your issue is that you have NO admin and you are still getting redirected to the other page, like if you had an admin, right? Can you add more debugging and tell us exactly which line of code is redirecting?

Comment: The main problem is when l post data form via register blade l have only reloaded the page. no debugging no errors. l don't know if middleware CheckSetup cases the issue

Comment: You do have 2 names on the routes being equal, the final URLs are going to be the same, so there should be no issue there. Can you check what final URL is generated on the form? Like see the form and check the HTML, what URL do you have in the action? I still think something is redirecting you, and it should be your middleware. This is basic debugging, so try to add as many logs or `dd` as possible until you find which code path the request is taking